# jest disable esModuleInterop warning without supressing console logs

Tags: node.js, jestjs, ts-jest

When I run `jest`, it always prints

```
ts-jest[config] (WARN) message TS151001:
If you have issues related to imports, you should consider setting `esModuleInterop` to `true` in your
TypeScript configuration file (usually `tsconfig.json`).
See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/01/31/announcing-typescript-2-7/#easier-ecmascript-module-interoperability for more information.
```

I do not want to set `esModuleInterop` to `true`.

I have seen `--silent` as a suggestion to supresses warnings, but this would also suppress every `console.log` I've made, which I don't want. (setting `--silent` also doesn't even suppress the warning for me for some reason)

How can I either disable all warnings or this specific warning in Jest while keeping `console.log` output?

Comment: You can ignore just that particular code by adding it to your jest config file: https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options/diagnostics#ignoring-some-error-codes

Answer (score 0):

you can get rid of that warning adding this to your jest.config:

```js
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': ['ts-jest', { diagnostics: { ignoreCodes: ['TS151001'] } }],
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
  }
}
```